# Separable Partial Differential Equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Solve the following PDE using separable equations.

Given $\frac{∂u}{∂x}$ = $\frac{∂u}{∂y}$

According to the textbook it says we assume u(x,y) = X(x)Y(y), we could easily see that the equation is separable and we would get

X'Y = XY' and it becomes

$\frac{X'}{X}$ = $\frac{Y'}{Y}$ = -λ  ; since both sides are independent  of x and y we say that they both equal to -λ

X' + λX = 0    and    Y' + λY = 0

Up to here is fine but I am having trouble understanding the 3 cases when 
λ= 0, λ=-α<sup>2</sup>, λ=+α<sup>2</sup>.

From the solution manual, it says that

X= C<sub>1</sub>e<sup>-λx</sup>

Y= C<sub>2</sub>e<sup>-λy</sup>

where U= XY = C<sub>3</sub>e<sup>-λ(x+y)</sup>

I am so confused to how did they approach this?

Comment: If it's a second order PDE, then you have three different cases, in terms of trig functions, exponentials, or polynomials. However, this one is first order, so it only has one case. Solve X, Y, and put them together.

Comment: I still don't understand

Comment: You have two ODEs, X' + aX= 0, Y' + aY = 0. Solve them, and use them to reconstruct u.